# Recursion depth problem inside a loop

Tags: warning-messages

I am solving a system of equation inside a loop.

This is my code:

```
Clear[lista];
lista = {};
U2 = 1;
U1 = -2/10;
Do[
  Do[Clear[L, δw, yd];
   solve = 
    Solve[{L + δw/2 == yinfl, 
       L + yd == 
        ydl, (U2 - U1)/(-U1*L - U1*yd)*
         yd^2/2 == δw, δw > 0, L > 0, 
       yd > 0, δw > yd}, {L, δw, yd}, Reals]
     If[solve != {},
      AppendTo[lista, 
       N[{yinfl, ydl, N[solve[[1, 1, 2]]], N[solve[[1, 2, 2]]], 
         N[solve[[1, 3, 2]]]}]], 
      AppendTo[lista, N[{yinfl, ydl, 0, 0, 0}]]];
   Export[
    "/home/mateus/loop_sol_sist_new.dat", lista], {ydl, 1, 1, 1/10}], {yinfl, 1, 1, 1/10}];
```

I got a error message:

```
Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of
```

I dont' know what is wrong.

Comment: You need a `;` after the `Solve` expression. By the way, `Do` can take multiple iterators, so you don't need nested `Do` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a refactored version of your code:

```
lista = {};
U2 = 1;
U1 = -2/10;

Do[
  solve = Solve[
     {L + δw/2 == yinfl, L + yd == ydl, (U2 - U1)/(-U1 L - U1 yd) yd^2/2 == δw, 
       δw > 0, L > 0, yd > 0, δw > yd}, 
     {L, δw, yd}, Reals
   ];
  If[solve != {},
    AppendTo[lista, Flatten@{yinfl, ydl, {L, δw, yd} /. solve[[1]]}],
    AppendTo[lista, {yinfl, ydl, 0, 0, 0}]
  ],
  {ydl, 1, 12/10, 1/10}, {yinfl, 1, 12/10, 1/10}
]

lista

(* Out:
{{1., 1., 0.333333, 1.33333, 0.666667}, {1.1, 1., 0.24503, 1.70994, 0.75497}, 
 {1.2, 1., 0.172253, 2.05549, 0.827747}, {1., 1.1, 0.486127, 1.02775, 0.613873}, 
 {1.1, 1.1, 0.366667, 1.46667, 0.733333}, {1.2, 1.1, 0.277507, 1.84499, 0.822493},
 {1., 1.2, 0., 0., 0.}, {1.1, 1.2, 0.517157, 1.16569, 0.682843}, 
 {1.2, 1.2, 0.4, 1.6, 0.8}}
*)
```

---

A more idiomatic version:

```
U2 = 1;
U1 = -2/10;

f = Flatten[
     {#1, #2,
      {L, δw, yd} /. 
       Solve[{L + δw/2 == #1, L + yd == #2, (U2 - U1)/(-U1 L - U1 yd) yd^2/2 == δw, 
              δw > 0, L > 0, yd > 0, δw > yd}, {L, δw, yd}, Reals]
     }]&;

solutions = f @@@ Tuples[{Range[1, 12/10, 1/10], Range[1, 12/10, 1/10]}] // N;
solutions /. {a__, L, δw, yd} :> {a, 0, 0, 0}
```